# Is it possible to use the Dev Containers VSCode extension on a Jetson Nano?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have a working Docker development container running on my Windows machine's VSCode, but it will not run on my Jetson Nano.

I can get Docker to work on the Jetson normally (outside of VSC) with my choice of base image.

However, when I modify the Dev Container's Dockerfile to *just* be `FROM <working_base_img>`, it still does not work.

I am no computer architecture expert and I can't really find anything about this online besides that I'm probably running into some x86 vs ARM issue.

So is it possible to use the VSC Dev Containers extension on a Jetson Nano? If so, how? If not, is there an alternative to run the same container for development purposes on both a Jetson and Windows/Mac?